# Array with unique values using array helper functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I was playing with **ES6** array helper functions *reduce()* and *find()*. I'm trying to display array of unique elements. But it is failing in case of value **0**. I'm not able to find what's wrong with my code. Please guide.

Here is my code snippet:

```
var arrayWithDuplicates = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 'a', 'a'];

var arrayWithUniqueValues = arrayWithDuplicates
                            .reduce((previous, item) => {
                                if(!previous.find(element => element === item)) {
                                    previous.push(item)
                                }
                                return previous;
                            }, []);

console.log('arrayWithUniqueValues', arrayWithUniqueValues)
```

I'm getting below output:

```
arrayWithUniqueValues [ 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'a' ]
```

Why I'm getting 0 twice while all other values are unique?

Comment: _"The find() method **returns the value** of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function."_, hence it returns `0` and that's a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: Use `some` instead of `find`.

Comment: Or just do `var arrayWithUniqueValues = [...new Set(arrayWithDuplicates)];`

Comment: @NenadVracar thank you for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

when you got 0,the code becomes :

```
arrayWithDuplicates.reduce(([0], 0) => {
                            if(!previous.find(element => element === item)) {
                            //![0].find(0=>0===0),return 0,so !0 means true
                                previous.push(item)
                            //so [0,0]
                            }
                            return previous;
                        });
```

a better way is

```
 let a=[...new Set([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 'a', 'a'])];//[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, "a"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same result by converting your array into a Set and back to an Array.

```
var arrayWithUniqueValues = [...new Set(arrayWithDuplicates)];
```

The reason your code doesn't work, by the way, is that `Array.prototype.find` returns the element it found. When you search for 0, it returns 0 and then `!0` is true. So 0 is added even if it is already in the array. You can do instead:

```
if (previous.indexOf(item) === - 1) {
    previous.push(item);
}
```